# Spring Cloud Data Flow for Kubernetes - Could not configure multiple kafka brokers

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to migrate my SCDF local server deployments to the k8s-based solution. But I've got some problems when handling the server configuration of the kafka broker-list for the apps.

I followed the instructions here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle
and downloaded the sample configuration from : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes at branch v1.7.2.RELEASE

Because we've already deployed a kafka cluster, I'd like to configure the broker- and zk-nodes in the server-config-kafka.yaml file so that we could use the same kafka cluster.

I configured my environmentVaribales like this:

```
    deployer:
      kubernetes:
        environmentVariables: >
            SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_BROKERS='172.16.3.192:9092,172.16.3.193:9092,172.16.3.194:9092',
            SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_ZK_NODES='172.16.3.192:2181,172.16.3.193:2181,172.16.3.194:2181'
```

but got an error when trying to deploy my SCDF stream: 
Invalid environment variable declared: 172.16.3.193:9092

How should I configure it to make it work? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `>` in your YAML

That's creating a block string, not a map of environment variables. [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210)

Also, if using CoreDNS in kubernetes, you should probably be using something like `kafka.default.cluster.local` for the value, rather than IP addresses, and similar for Zookeeper

Comment: thx for the reply :) . 
AFAK, spring deployer for k8s reads the environment variables from block strings seperated with comma, and not from maps —— that's acctually what make the things difficult here, beacause the spring cloud stream reads also such block strings so I have to find a way to pack them in the env-variables. 
And the IP addresses are just for tests, I'll replace them with domain names later.

Comment: Okay, I've not used spring deployer... And, they're not "domain names", but pod addresses. A pod, by default, doesn't have a static ip